# Facebook iOS SDK and unicode

Tags: objective-c, facebook, unicode, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the facebook iOS SDK and I keep getting strings of data like "\U9ec3\U6de8\U5a77" in the Graph API. What's wrong? This is the code I'm using:

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result{
   NSLog(@"%@",[result description]);
}


- (void)requestFeed:(NSString *)path withDelegate:(id)delegate{
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=%@&client_secret=%@",APP_ID,APP_SECRET]]];

    NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

    NSString *access_token = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] substringFromIndex:13];

    NSLog(@"%@",access_token);

    [fb requestWithGraphPath:path andParams:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:access_token,@"access_token", nil] andDelegate:delegate];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your string `'\u9ec3\u6de8\u5a77'` is equivalent to `'黃淨婷'`.

This appears to be [someone's name](http://zh-tw.facebook.com/people/%E9%BB%83%E6%B7%A8%E5%A9%B7/1746501109) in Chinese. According to Google Translate, it is read as "Huáng Jìng-tíng" in Mandarin.